# Gcc linker automagically finds needed extra libraries

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I am developing and testing some code on 2 different machines: my own *buntu laptop and a remote linux machine configured by someone else.

My code uses a library, let's say libfoo, that in turn depends on, say, libbase.
I would like to keep a single makefile across both the machines, but I found out things works differently when I build my project (with GCC):

- On my laptop, I need to specify -lfoo -lbase for the code to link
  correctly.
- On the remote machine, I only need the -lfoo flag, and the linker
  somehow picks up the base library automagically.

Anyone knows what is going on? Is there any flag that might have been passed when building libfoo from source that made this automatical "depencency detection" possible?

PS: I know I could just specify every library in the make file, but keeping the list of flags to the minimum looks interesting, and I would like to know what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both `-lfoo` and `-lbase` refer to some shared libraries `libfoo.so` and `libbase.so` (perhaps with some version number).

On the remote machine, `libfoo.so` was built and linked to `libbase.so`, perhaps from some `foo1.c` and `foo2.c` like

```
 gcc -Wall -O -fPIC foo1.c -o foo1.pic.o
 gcc -Wall -O -fPIC foo2.c -o foo2.pic.o
 gcc -shared -O foo1.pic.o foo2.pic.o -lbase -o libfoo.so
```

(of course, probably some `Makefile` did run above commands thru `make`)

On your own laptop, you (or your distribution maker) did not link `-lbase` inside `libfoo.so`

Read [Drepper's how to write shared library](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf%E2%80%8E) (long) paper (and the [program library howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/))

<sup>It is possible to link a shared (low-level) library inside another (higher-level) shared library (and that is not possible with static libraries `libfoo.a`).</sup>

You could use `ldd`  on (the absolute path of) your libraries `libfoo.so` and `libbase.so` to find out how they have been linked.

Comment: That is a bit strange... The `base` library is actually the `epetra` library, and this is the relevant line in the results of `ldd` on the `foo` library: `libepetra.so.11 => /usr/local/lib/libepetra.so.11 (0x00007fbce0dfc000)` and as far as I can tell this looks like regularly linked.